# Remove text outside of [] {} () bracket

Tags: php, regex, regexp-replace

I have a string, from which I want to keep text inside a pair of brackets and remove everything outside of the brackets:

> Hello [123] {45} world (67)
> Hello There (8) [9] {0}

Desired output:
[123] {45} (67) (8) [9] {0}

Code tried but fails:

```
$re = '/[^()]*+(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))[^()]*+/';
$text = preg_replace($re, '$1', $text);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the values in the string are always an opening bracket paired up with a closing bracket and no nested parts, you can match all the bracket pairs which you want to keep, and match all other character except the brackets that you want to remove.

```
(?:\[[^][]*]|\([^()]*\)|{[^{}]*})(*SKIP)(*F)|[^][(){}]+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture gorup

  - `\[[^][]*]` Match from `[...]`
  - `|` Or
  - `\([^()]*\)` Match from `(...)`
  - `|` Or
  - `{[^{}]*}` Match from `{...}`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(*SKIP)(*F)|` [consume characters that you want to avoid, and that must not be a part of the match result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex)
- `[^][(){}]+` Match 1+ times any char other than 1 of the listed

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GQOd2r/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/br8n9)

**Example code**

```
$re = '/(?:\[[^][]*]|\([^()]*\)|{[^{}]*})(*SKIP)(*F)|[^][(){}]+/m';
$str = 'Hello [123] {45} world (67)
Hello There (8) [9] {0}';

$result = preg_replace($re, '', $str);

echo $result;
```

**Output**

```
[123]{45}(67)(8)[9]{0}
```

If you want to remove all other values:

```
(?:\[[^][]*]|\([^()]*\)|{[^{}]*})(*SKIP)(*F)|.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0UPVHH/1)

Comment: I will mark this as an answer, just need one more help What if $str has some other characters like @# also outside the bracket which I want to keep.

Comment: @www.friend0.in You can add those characters to the character class at the end to exclude matching them `(?:\[[^][]*]|\([^()]*\)|{[^{}]*})(*SKIP)(*F)|[^][(){}@#]+` See  https://regex101.com/r/kGLXjU/1

Comment: Hi. Just a follow up question: I need to do the same thing but with the difference that I need the parentheses themselves to go away as well, so in your example I'd need it to return just "1234567890". What do I need to change?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you wanted to target nested stuff as well. There are already [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D%20balanced%20parentheses) about how to match balanced parenthesis. Adjust one of those patterns to fit your needs, e.g. something like

```
$pattern = '/\((?:[^)(]*(?R)?)*+\)|\{(?:[^}{]*+(?R)?)*\}|\[(?:[^][]*+(?R)?)*\]/';
```

You can [try this on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YdHGh0/2). Extract those [with `preg_match_all` and `implode` the matches](https://tio.run/##TY9Lb8IwEITv@RV7qJTd0Ir0AX03V46o6s1xUUiWJsLYlmOEquDfnibQSr3M4ZvVzKytbd@/ZMvFMoouWu/gFeIFK2VAXN/cSujuZgEOxqkKcH5PcPY@anYM@EAgHoebNERYMVvU3HquRKO7De5JaImavoOkTqxdUW7ZtzIQXIHwddNKwEOjFIE2HnDtuNhS/DzMsIX37PQ4ZZojZk/ik1AmmL1TRskkp2PenWjoZDL5xXk45uJEpfhH5XSMbDZoHX@tdoUv61WhFP6VXML49aBm7wneIKUIgMvaQLOzylSMMcRnW6SShqy@/wE).

```
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $out) > 0)
  echo implode(' ', $out[0]);
```

If you need to match the stuff outside, even with this pattern you can use [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) that also used @Thefourthbird [in his elaborately answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64741019/5527985)! For skipping the bracketed [see this other demo](https://regex101.com/r/YdHGh0/4).

Comment: Haven't  seen you for a while, but I remember you created some cool patterns in the past. This one  is also very nice :-) +1

Comment: Good to see you again too @Thefourthbird : ) Thanks you!

Comment: Great code, it also kept the space and thus improved readability. Just need one more help; What if $str has some other characters like @# outside the bracket which I want to keep.

Comment: @www.friend0.in Well, I just used a space for imploding - acutally nothing is left outside, you wrote *remove everything outside of the brackets* : ). If you want to keep the original spaces or add characters, just attach another alternation to the pattern, e.g.: [`|[@# ]`](https://regex101.com/r/MhrA3Z/1/) and implode on empty space.

Comment: @www.friend0.in fyi, that you can use this pattern with `(*SKIP)(*F)` as well and match stuff outside the brackets (similar the fourth bird), [see this demo](https://regex101.com/r/YdHGh0/4) - with the difference, that it works on nested stuff.

Comment: @bobblebubble Thnx a ton buddy for your help & the code

Answer (score 1):

If the brackets are not nested, the following should suffice:

```regex
[^[{(\]})]+(?=[[{(]|$)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JRFfjq/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

```regex
[^[{(\]})]+     # Match one or more characters except for opening/closing bracket chars.
(?=[[{(]|$)     # A positive Lookahead to ensure that the match is either followed by
                # an opening bracket char or is at the end of the string.
```

Comment: It also fits (this]. I think a back reference is required.